# localStorage (самый простой способ)

Tags: javascript, css, localstorage

Не так вопрос по решению, как вопрос как разобраться в localStorage, тоесть записывать самые простые методы и извлекать их.
На примере хочу разобаться как сделать темный бэкграунд для сайта с возможностью сохранения его после перезагружки страницы.

HTML

```
<button onclick="colorBg()">Color</button>
```

CSS

```
body.color-background{
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

JS

```
function colorBg() { 
  document.body.classList.toggle('.color-background');
 }
```

Нужно понять как сделать так, что бы `localStorage` записалось `colorBg()` и при перезагрузке страницы оставался темный бэкграунд. Спасибо!

Comment: в `localStorage` можно записывать **только** строки.

Comment: Вам именно метод нужно сохранить или просто цвет заднего фона?

Answer (score -3):

Записываете в локал сторадж нужный метод как строку:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedVar", "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'gold'");
```

В документе первым делом его запускаете в работу:

```
eval(localStorage.getItem("savedVar"));
```

Comment: К сожалению такой метод не работает(

Comment: Почему? Я проверил - работает. Вам надо что-то иное?

Comment: Минусящие, может, поясните, что вам не так?

Comment: Минусящие, думаю, заботятся о 1) безопасности 2) Наличии обработки ошибок.
eval в принципе для такого не рекомендуется употреблять

Comment: а какое это отношение имеет к поставленной задаче?

Comment: @Инквизитор можно сделать ту же инъекцию скрипта вместо `eval`, что очевидно поддерживает большее кол-во сайтов. К тому же стоило бы объяснить тс'у что лучше сохранять сам цвет фона, а не метод и используя уже его (цвет), менять цвет текущего фона.

Comment: Стопэ.

Вопрос был в том, как в локалСторедж засунуть метод и выудить его, а не в том, насколько это безопасно и как правильно поступить (так-то я согласен с тем, что в ЛС надо хранить значения). 

Что за дискриминация и субъективизм?